# Collecting multiple sensor values from same Bacnet controller

Tags: json, thingsboard, bacnet

I have managed to setup both BACnet and MQTT connectors and produce a data flow to both MQTT and dashboard.
However I am unsure of the exact syntax I need to use in my bacnet.json for pulling multiple sensors in the same BACnet controller.
Any pointers or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sample config files in the documentation:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/config/bacnet/

Comment: Hi mdeuchert, Thanks for you answer however I have read that documentation over and over, it does not give example or how to collect more than one sensor value from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're probably referring to setting up several "attributes" (/BACnet 'objects'/controller 'points'):

https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/config/bacnet/#key-settings-for-attributes